# Delete XAML Build Definition on VSTS

Tags: build, azure-devops, definition

How can I delete an old XAML build definition on VSTS? I cannot find any where to delete it.

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS not support XAML build (currently) so you can't see the XAML build definitions on VSTS.

You can see the XAML build definitions via Visual Studio in the Team Explorer, after you connect to your VSTS account, then you should have the ability to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it through Web Access, check this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the answer to the question.